# Intersected, buffered polygon - ArcGIS API for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, buffer, intersection, arcgis

I am using Silverlight (4) to create an application in (VS 2010). I utilized the ArcGIS API’s for Silverlight to generate the following scenario:

1. I buffered a polyline to a variable distance.
2. I then retrieve all but only those polygons that are overlapped by the buffer.
3. I then intersect the overlapped portions to separate them.
4. Attaining the separated overlapped portions, I was about to utilize the Area and perimeter service to retrieve the areas of the portions, but realized that this last step would be in the wind.

I have no problem coding the above scenario except; I now realize that step 4 would not be very useful at this point, since I have no way of sharing data between the separated overlapped portions to the original polygons. Imagine if you will; before I separated the overlapped portions from the polygons, they had data tied to them; such as `valuationNumber` and `volume`, but after the separation due to the intersection service, the separated portions seems blank with no data. My goal is to have a list highlighting the `valuationNumber`, `volume`, and the area of the separated portion.

Something like:

Valuation:
`12345678`

Volume:
`1234/123`

Area of Separation (M):
`12`

Any, and I mean any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well then, I would suppose I created a work around, I wonder if there is a right way out there though. Anyhow, I did the following:

I created a Dictionary Object and populated it with the Attribute values of the original polygon just as they are created. Then, just as the overlapped portions are being created I assigned the attribute values from my Dictionary. So, now the values match up, and all binding works just fine. 

But hey, if anyone know a better way; I'm all eyes.

//Houdini

Comment: In fact, to make matters seem a bit better, I made an improvement on the work around. I create a class with the fields I wanted to be in both original and separated portions. Then added this class as the value parameter of my dictionary object I spoke of earlier, then followed the same procedure. Now I have all the fields being mapped to in XAML working nicely (for now).

Answer (score 0):

[copied and pasted my comments from above due to laziness]

Well then, I would suppose I created a work around, I wonder if there is a right way out there though. Anyhow, I did the following: I created a Dictionary Object and populated it with the Attribute values of the original polygon just as they are created. Then, just as the overlapped portions are being created I assigned the attribute values from my Dictionary. So, now the values match up, and all binding works just fine. But hey, if anyone know a better way; I'm all eyes.

In fact, to make matters seem a bit better, I made an improvement on the work around. I create a class with the fields I wanted to be in both original and separated portions. Then added this class as the value parameter of my dictionary object I spoke of earlier, then followed the same procedure. Now I have all the fields being mapped to in XAML working nicely (for now).